# How can I reproduce this chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am working on reproducing the chart attached. The chart shows the interquantile range of some countries for the categories shown on the y-axis, for the two year 2008 and 2018. Any idea how can I do this in excel? I have all the data ready I just want to do the chart.
[image]

Comment: Check out [Floating Bars in Excel Charts](https://peltiertech.com/floating-bars-excel-charts/) for a bunch of techniques, and pay attention to stacked column charts and up-down bars in line charts. Also, here's an example of such a chart in practice: [Salary Chart: Plot Markers on Floating Bars](https://peltiertech.com/salary-chart-plot-markers-on-floating-bars/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Excel will not natively do this type of graph.  The closest I could come was a single year using the Stock Graph.  It uses three series to define the graph.  First series will be the max of your bar, the second will be the min of your bar and the third will be the dot value.  Format the line so they are wider and transparent and the colour you want.  click on the dot marker and change its marker to a circle and black.

You can cheat and make to graphs one for each year and then superimpose them on top of each other with a slight horizontal offset.  You then need to do things like turn off the background fill, the axis, etc so you don't see double the info.  Make sure you manually set the max and min values to the same in each graph.  If you do not the automatic values may not be the same for both graphs and you will wind up with two different vertical scales.  Impossible to line up properly.

If you do it correctly, you can wind up getting something that looks like this:

[image]

Note you cannot make the graphs their own tab as there would be no way to superimpose the second graph on top.

TIP:  Set up one graph they way you need it to look with all the information showing.  When you are done copy the graph and paste it back in.  Position the graph where you want it then select it, right click and click on "Select data..."  Then choose your second year of data.  Change the colour of your vertical bar then start turning features off.

I laid my sample data out as follows:

[image]

In order to get your vertical line work, you can either draw the lines in manually (recommended) or you can try playing with ticks marks and vertical axis crossing points (may not be possible)

Comment: Once you figure out a proper procedural script, you can probably automate much of this process going forward using something like [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php)